# Calculating a coefficient of recovery python. Geotiff recoveryrate in a 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, trendline

I'm an extreme python novice and am trying to work with some arrays. 
I have 10 years of geotifs, where i am comparing the ndvi from one year to the next. I'm trying to calculate the coefficient of recovery (a trendline based on the year to year recovery rate) for each pixel over the years. I can make these into a 3d array if that helps. Hopefully this is the right amount of info for you guys to help me out!

```
x= np.array(range(2002,2012))
pfarray = []
rrarrays = []
for yr in range(len(band3)):
    b3 = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(band3[yr])
    b4 = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(band4[yr])    
    ndvi = (b4 - b3)/(b4 + b3)
    ndvihealthy = ndvi[baarray==2]    
    rr = ndvi/ndvihealthy.mean()
    rrarrays.append(rr)
    rr3d = np.dstack(rrarrays) 
    for pixel in rr:
        pf = np.polyfit(x,rr,1)
        pfarray.append(pf)
```

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: Sorry! The polyfit, function is giving an error message. "Expected x and y to have the same length"